# forEach loop inside an asynchronous function - Javascript

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am new to Node JS and I'm struggling to understand how to run a for loop inside an asynchronous function. There is another async function inside the for loop.

I should be getting a response of some values in `promArray`. However, I am getting an empty array.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

const options2 = {
    uri: 'uri',
    method: 'GET',
    auth: {
        'user': 'username',
        'pass': 'password'
    }
};
var promArray = [];


function executeMethod() {

    rp(options2).then(function(body) {

        const jsonData = JSON.parse(body).result;
        // iterate through the pods

        jsonData.forEach(element => {
            promArray.push(getProjectName(element.u_hig_proj_name.value))
        });


    });

    return Promise.all(promArray);
}

function getProjectName(projectSysId) {
    const projectTableAttrbutes = {
        uri: 'uri',
        method: 'GET',
        auth: {
            'user': 'username',
            'pass': 'password'
        }
    };
    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
        // call the project table
        rp(projectTableAttrbutes).then(function(body) {
            //console.log(JSON.parse(body).result.name);
            res(JSON.parse(body).result.name);
        })
    })
}


// final execution 

executeMethod().then(function(done) {

    console.log(done);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your `forEach` is within the `then` block. That means that it will be executed asynchronously.

Your return statement however is located outside of the `then`, so it will be executed immediately, before the promise has resolved and the `then` block has run. Thats why it's empty.

This would be a possible solution:

```
function executeMethod() {
    return rp(options2).then(function(body) {

        const jsonData = JSON.parse(body).result;
        // iterate through the pods

        jsonData.forEach(element => {
            promArray.push(getProjectName(element.u_hig_proj_name.value))
        });

        return Promise.all(promArray);

    });
}
```

In this solution, the two promises are chained and executed consecutively. First, the outer promise is returned (`return rp(...)`). Within it's `then` block, the second promise is returned (`return Promise.all(...)`). That will be the final value, that `executeMethod` will resolve with.

[I highly recommend checking out this article](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining#returning-promises) to learn more about promise chaining, since it is a crucial tool when working with promises.

Answer (score 0):

When you first call `executeMethod()`, your `promArray` is empty, so all of the promises in the array (that is, all zero of them) are resolved, so the promise resolves right away. I'm guessing the promises you're actually interested in are those generated in the `jsonData.forEach` call, since you're adding those to `promArray`. Therefore, I'd recommend actually saying `jsonData.map` and then returning each of those `getProjectName` calls as promises, then wrap the whole `.map` call in `Promise.all`:

```
return Promise.all(
    jsonData.map(
        element => getProjectName(element.u_hig_proj_name.value)
    )
);
```

And then you can use that like another promise.

---

Also, I don't quite understand what you're doing in the `getProjectName` function - why are you creating a new Promise wrapper around the request? It's already a promise.